# SO_REUSEADDR and AF_UNIX

Tags: sockets, unix, posix

## The fact

In the POSIX documentation, I can't see anything preventing the use of the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option with `AF_UNIX` for UNIX Domain Sockets.

However, it invariably fails at `bind` time if the socket node already exists, and seems to be ignored and seems it is required to unlink the socket node on the file‑system first prior to invoke `bind`; in short, it does not reuse the address. There are plenty of threads on the web about this issue, and none with a solution.

## The question

I won't insist, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work (seems to be the same at least on both BSD and Linux systems), and just have a question: is this normal behaviour or not? Is there any pointers suggesting it should be supported, or on the opposite, any pointers suggesting it should not? Or is this unspecified? Note the question is asked in the POSIX context, not in any particular platform context.

I welcome any POSIX reference on the matter.

### Extra: a tiny snippet to not blindly `unlink` who‑know‑what

I've seen some threads on the web, suggesting to `unlink` any node of the expected name prior to `bind`. I feel it's unsafe, and one should only unlink a node which is already a socket node in this case: ex. it's probably wrong, to unlink a text file named `mysocket` to recreate a socket node of the same name in place. In this purpose, here is a tiny snippet:

```
/* Create the socket node
 * ----------------------
 * Note `SO_REUSEADDR` does not work with `AF_UNIX` sockets,
 * so we will have to unlink the socket node if it already exists,
 * before we bind. For safety, we won't unlink an already existing node
 * which is not a socket node. 
 */

status = stat (path, &st);
if (status == 0) {
   /* A file already exists. Check if this file is a socket node.
    *   * If yes: unlink it.
    *   * If no: treat it as an error condition.
    */
   if ((st.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFSOCK) {
      status = unlink (path);
      if (status != 0) {
         perror ("Error unlinking the socket node");
         exit (1);
      }
   }
   else {
      /* We won't unlink to create a socket in place of who-know-what.
       * Note: don't use `perror` here, as `status == 0` (this is an
       * error we've defined, not an error returned by a system-call).
       */
      fprintf (stderr, "The path already exists and is not a socket node.\n");
      exit (1);
   }
}
else {
   if (errno == ENOENT) {
      /* No file of the same path: do nothing. */
   }
   else {
      perror ("Error stating the socket node path");
      exit (1);
   }
}

/* … invoke `bind` here, which will create the socket node … */
```

Comment: Just to be clear: are you asking for a citation in a POSIX specification that says whether or not this behavior is correct, or are you asking how common POSIX implementations behave?

Comment: I was wondering if common POSIX implementations (well, at least Linux and BSD) are right or wrong; so yes, I would say I'm looking for something like a citation from POSIX. Note I'm aware this may just be unspecified. P.S. I will add a tiny snippet which I believe is useful, to the initial post.

Comment: I think you should add one more case. If the file exists and is a socket, attempt a `connect()`. If that fails, then no service is listening on that socket so it can safely be deleted. Also I think that deleting a file which is not a socket should not happen automatically. That could be an important file!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I only have access to one POSIX specification document, which is [System Interfaces](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html), so I'm going to do my best from here.

Our specification spelunking adventure must of course start in [2.10.6 Use of Options](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_16), which defines the `SO_REUSEADDR` option as follows:

> The SO_REUSEADDR option indicates that the rules used in validating addresses supplied in a bind() should allow reuse of local addresses. Operation of this option is protocol-specific. The default value for SO_REUSEADDR is off; that is, reuse of local addresses is not permitted.

This paragraph basically disclaims any specification of what this option truly does, by delegating it to the specification of the underlying protocol.

[Section 2.10.17 Use of Sockets for Local UNIX Connections](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_17) describes the mechanics of creating UNIX domain sockets, but really the only thing it tells us is what socket type constant to use and which struct to use for addresses. [The documentation for the `sockaddr_un` struct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_un.h.html) tells us only about its format, not about its behavior on `bind`.

[The documentation for `bind` itself](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html#tag_16_38) is understandably protocol-agnostic, telling us only what happens when the address is already in use, not the circumstances under which re-binding the same socket is valid.

Although it's not a POSIX standard document, Fujitsu has [a document on the POSIX sockets API](http://manuals.ts.fujitsu.com/file/4686/posix_s.pdf) which is interesting if only because it's not specifically about Linux or BSD. Section 2.6.4 of this document has the following to say about the behavior of `bind` on UNIX sockets:

> The path name, which must be specified in the `sun.sun_path` component, is created as a file in the file system using `bind()`. The process that calls `bind()` must therefore have write rights to the directory in which the file is to be written. The system does not delete the file. It should therefore be deleted by the process when it is no longer required.

Although this says nothing about `SO_REUSEADDR` in particular, it does state that the behavior of `bind` is to *create* a file, and that it is the responsibility of the binding process to remove it when it's no longer being used.

Finally, this document's description of `setsockopt` has the following to say about `SO_REUSEADDR`:

> Specifies that the rules for the validity check on the addresses specified for bind() should permit the reuse of local addresses **provided this is supported by the protocol**.

So while this makes no specific mention of `AF_UNIX`, it *does* acknowledge that this option doesn't apply to all protocols.

I also found [a (non-authoritative) summary describing the *intended* purpose of `SO_REUSEADDR`](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml):

> This socket option tells the kernel that even if this port is busy (in the `TIME_WAIT` state), go ahead and reuse it anyway.  If it is busy, but with another state, you will still get an address already in use error.

The `TIME_WAIT` state exists primarily for Internet-facing sockets to avoid a new program binding to a port that was recently being used by another program and inadvertently receiving packets relating to the old program. This problem is arguably not applicable to UNIX domain sockets because it's very unlikely that two programs would attempt to create a socket at the same path, so if `TIME_WAIT` is not implemented for UNIX sockets then that could be one (approximation of an) explanation for why `SO_REUSEADDR` does not apply to `AF_UNIX`.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful reply Martin, and for the link to the PDF at Fujitsu. I agree about the interpretation to be done of the `TIME_WAIT` mention, and finally, that's not unspecified, but not applicable. Just a tiny thing: I believe you've made an error with the last word and you were to say “does not apply to `AF_UNIX`” instead “does not apply to `AF_INET`”. Enjoy a nice day!

Comment: Nobody gives a shit about posix anymore. What are the dominating OS now do? Also is the metnioned stupid 104 byte sun_path still existing? Please don't tell me it does just based on the definition in any userspace header.

Comment: This question was specifically about what is/was required by POSIX standards. If you want to know what a specific currently-maintained OS does then of course you can try it yourself to see, or if you care about Linux then you can read the source code for the kernel to learn how it behaves.