# Python 2.7 / Linux: socket library binding type error

Tags: python, linux, sockets, python-2.7, bind

I am attempting to write a very simple server in python.

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket to listen on
server = socket.socket(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Prevent from 'address already in use' upon server restart
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind the socket to port 8081 on all interfaces
server_address = ('localhost', 8081)
print 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
server.bind(server_address)
```

I have read what I think to be correct documentation for the socket library, and it suggests that the server.bind() takes an argument of a tuple. However, I get this error:

```
starting up on localhost port 8081
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    server.bind(server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: argument must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple
```

I have changed the argument to only a string, as the error warning suggests, and I get a

```
[Errno 98] Address already in use
```

error. I thought that the 8th line was in place to prevent that. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to the `socket.socket` should be address family:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Except that, your code should work.

**Reason of the error message**: *argument must be string ...*

In Linux, the value of the `socket.SOL_SOCKET` is 1 which is equal to the value of `socket.AF_UNIX`. Unix domain socket (AF_UNIX) use path (string) as a address

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.AF_UNIX
1
>>> socket.SOL_SOCKET
1
```

**UPDATE**

Regarding *Already already in use* error, see [SO_REUSEADDR and AF_UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15716302/2225682).